# Anúncios não aparecem no Cordova SDK

Tags: apache-cordova

A partir da API 2.0 meus anúncios, banners e insterticial não aparecem. O banner não mostra indício, o intersticial carrega o spinner logo em seguida desaparece.

Já verifiquei minha API Key e meu código está correto.

Versão do cordova > 6.3.1
Versão do plugin Appodeal > 1.14.9

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que ter esses arquivos na sua Lib:

> yandex-metrica-2.41.jar
>   unity-ads-2.0.4.jar
>
> my-target-4.5.10.jar
>
> flurry-analytics-6.5.0.jar
>
> chartboost-6.5.1.jar
>
> appodeal-1.15.5.jar
>
> applovin-6.3.0.jar

importar o mudolo Chetah-Moblile(renomeie ele deste jeito tire aquele "3-4-7"algo assim)
No Gradle adicione nas dependencias

> compile project(':cheetah-mobile')
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'

caso de erro multi dex
adicione isto ao Gradle.properties

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize\=2048m -Xmx2048m

embaixo de algo parecido com isto

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8